# Input multiple words and match them to lists containing that word

Tags: python, excel, list, find, match

In excel I have many `x` and `y` columns and rows. I want to enter a word and the lists that contain that word print out the `name` of that column. For example:

| A | B | C | D | E |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Tomato | orange | apple | tire | donut |
| red | orange | red | black | brown |
| round | round | round | round | round |
| stem | stem | stem | rubber | hole |
| veggie | fruit | fruit | tread | sweet |

I type in "Round" and then the output will be the first row (tomato, orange, apple, tire, donut) since all the columns contain the word round.

How would I do this in python? I have no clue. Please help me!!! :D

Comment: you can use [`pandas.DataFrame`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.html).

Comment: Hi there @kawitzan and welcome to the site! Might I suggest that you review the [How to ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) pages and enjoy the [site tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour). It is expected that you have tried to solve your issue on your own first and provide details of what you have done/ a minimum reproducible example of any issues.

Answer (score 0):

Incredibly, I made it.

I'm a beginner, just read the pandas material, I've used numpy before, they are similar.

```py
import pandas as pd

arr = [
    ["Tomato", "orange", "apple", "tire", "donut"],

    ["red", "orange", "red", "black", "brown"],

    ["round", "round", "round", "round", "round"],

    ["stem", "stem", "stem", "rubber", "hole"],

    ["veggie", "fruit", "fruit", "tread", "sweet"]
]

df = pd.DataFrame(arr)
res = df.loc[0, lambda df: [i for i in df.columns if 'round' in df[i].values]].tolist()

print(res)
```

Output:

```
['Tomato', 'orange', 'apple', 'tire', 'donut']
```

Comment: Thank you very much Bro! I am new to this space (have basic codeacadamy skillz) so sometimes super simple things are hard to find out

Comment: Probably just `res = df.loc[0, df.eq('round').any(axis=0)].tolist()` would be better. Though if I'm reading the question correctly, "print out the name of that column" seems to imply that the first row should be column names which depending on how that's read into pandas might mean that the answer should be `res = df.columns[df.eq('round').any(axis=0)].tolist()`

Comment: thank you sir! !

Comment: @HenryEcker Oh, that's so cool, really awesome. Can you add an answer to this question, I will delete this answer.